# Converting isPrime() Python to Haskell

Tags: python, haskell, primes, primality-test

I have a working (albeit inefficient) function to check if a number is prime in Python and I'd like to convert it to Haskell. Efficiency doesn't matter to me right now as I am focusing primarily on making a readable algorithm in Haskell that uses language features a beginner would understand.

I'm new to Haskell so I may have the wrong mindset about how to approach this. My basic algorithm is to check if a number is odd and above 2 and if so, check if it's divisible by any number before until 2.

Problem: I don't know how to set `i` equal to an increasing term in the range `[2..n]`.

*Question: Is there a way to iterate over a range with a variable and refer to it?*

---

Python:

```py
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2: 
        return False # by definition, numbers smaller than 2 are not prime
    if n == 2: # edge case, 2 is the only even number that is prime
        return True
    if (n % 2) == 0:
        return False # if even, n is not prime (except 2)
    else:
        for i in range(2,n): #iterate from 2 to the input(n)-1 (since range() is non-inclusive of stop param)
            if (n % i == 0): #if n is divisible by a number that isn't 1 or itself...
                return False # ...it isn't prime
    return True
```

Haskell (What I have so far):

```hs
isPrimeInner :: Int -> Bool
isPrimeInner n = map (n `rem` i == 0) [2..n] where i 
   -- I don't know how to set i equal to an increasing term 
   -- in the range [2..n]

isPrime :: Int -> Bool 
isPrime 2 = True -- edge case
isPrime n = if n < 2 
              then False 
            else if n `rem` 2 == 0 
              then False
            else isPrimeInner n
```

Comment: *"I don't know how to set i equal to an increasing term in the range [2..n]"* You could use a [lambda expression](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function).

Comment: So would I use that to modify i every time map performs one iteration? 

For example: [2..n]!!i where (\i -> i + 1)?

Comment: ``map (\i -> n `rem` i == 0) [2..n-1]`` will produce a list of booleans. Some functions like `and` and `or` can consume that list and produce a single boolean. You might need `not` as well. (Alternatively, use `any` or `all` from the libraries.)

Comment: @chi or it can be re-implemented with LC and `null` easily and clearly. :)

Comment: @chi yeah I just realized that was a mistake as well. What I really should be doing is checking each value in the range and returning False as soon as a divisor (other than 1) is found

Comment: In Haskell, `and (some list)` will evaluate the list only until the first false. Don't be afraid to produce the full list of booleans apparently trying all divisors: Haskell will not actually try all of them but only as many as demanded by `and`. The net result is that as soon as the first divisor is found you exit the "loop", so to speak.

Comment: in fact, thanks to Haskell's lazy evaluation, lists *are* loops, and data structures are like descriptions of computations to be done to populate them.

Comment: A Haskell list is a linked list, but behaves a lot like a generator in Python.

Comment: @chepner [with *pointers* and all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)? of course not, you'll say, and I'll agree. in fact, nothing in its data type definition says anything about pointers or linking. :) an implementation could implement it as anything by her choosing (including arrays) as long as the semantics of access are preserved. the [relevant Report section](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-340003.7) (and the links there) does not give any complexity guarantees (inherent in the "linked list" concept) and never even mentions that word. (contd.)

Comment: the singly-linked-list data structure makes it very easy to *efficiently* insert an element at any list position, including its end; or remove it; it makes it easy to maintain a growing/shrinking circular buffer; etc. . nothing of the sorts is even remotely possible with Haskell's `[]` data type.

Comment: @WillNess My point was that `map f [2..n]` doesn't call `f` on any element of the list until and as you iterate over the list "returned" by `map`. Maybe the better Python analogy is that `map f [2..n]` is much more like Python `map(f, range(2,n+1))` than `[f(x) for x in list(range(2,n+1))]`.

Comment: @chepner I'm just always peeved by this "`[]` is linked list" thing. :) as for Python, I don't know Python, I just read it as a pseudocode. :) but I thought it had generator comprehensions, so maybe something like `[f(x) for x in range(2,n+1)]` is OK? (or is it with the `( )` parens?....).

Comment: In Python, `map(f, range(2, n+1))` is roughly equivalent to the generator expression `(f(x) for x in range(2, n+1))`, which lazily applies `f` to a value as you iterate. The list comprehension `[f(x) for x in range(2, n+1)]` *immediately* builds a list (which is really a dynamically allocated, resizable array) containing the results of each function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest done with List Comprehensions:

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = n > 1 && ( n == 2 ||
   null [ () | i <- [2..n-1], rem n i == 0] )
   --          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here `i` is drawn from the range `2 .. n-1`, i.e. it takes on the increasing values from `2` to `n-1`, one at a time.

When it divides `n` evenly without a remainder, a `()` value is produced as a member of the output list, which is then tested for being empty, with  `null`. The code thus expresses the concept "there does *not* exist such `i` from `2` to `n-1` that divides `n` evenly".

The `i <- [2..n-1]` part is known as a *generator* part of a list comprehension, and `rem n i == 0` a *test expression*.

Testing:

```hs
> filter isPrime [0..545]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,
137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,
271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,
431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541]
it :: [Int]

> length it
100
```

Thanks to Haskell's lazy evaluation, when given a composite argument `n`, `isPrime` fails as soon as possible, with the *smallest* divisor `i` of `n`.

Comment: Why is the type change to Integral necessary?

Comment: no, it isn't, it just something GHCi derived for me. :)

Comment: Ah. I tried using Int but that causes an error. It's a requirement that the function takes an Int so is it possible to write the function in such a way that it takes an Int rather than an Integral?

Comment: there is no error. I've updated the answer. it works with `Int` just as well.

Comment: Huh, that's strange. And you're right no error when I copy paste from here. I was getting this before: "* Expected kind `* -> Constraint', but `Int' has kind `*'
    * In the type signature: isPrime :: Int a => a -> Bool"

Comment: right, that is an invalid signature. `Int` is a simple type, but `Int a` would be a "constraint", like `Integral a`. Only constraints go to the left of `=>`. You could use `isPrime :: a ~ Int => a -> Bool` but that is just superfluous.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Last question, could you explain what the () does in the LC What exactly is a () value?

Comment: the `()` is an unimportant value. We could use `1`, `True`, or anything else there too, since we only check whether the list is empty or not; so the value itself is unimportant. and in Haskell, the unimportant value is `()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no assignment in Haskell. Unfortunately you hit a topic that requires you to learn a new concept: Instead of focusing on a single value (`x`) you should focus on the complete range/list of values.

Let's assume `n = 8`. A Python programmer might iterate (`x in i in range(2, n)`), a Haskell programmer might convert the input list `[2..n]` into a result list and continue to solve the problem from there:

```
xs = [   2,     3,    4,     5, ...]  -- input [2..n]
ys = [True, False, True, False, ...]  -- the resulting list of the divisibility test
```

Therefore I propose to break the problem down and solve the two sub-problems:

1. How to compute `ys` from `xs`?
2. Assuming your have the list of divisibility tests (`ys`). How can you solve your original problem? In your case having *any* `True` value as an element is important. Fortunately there is a function [`any`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/any_f.html) that can help you.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. For subproblem 1, I think I can use map to apply a test to every element of the list xs (the test being n `rem` i ==  0). As mentioned above, the only problem with this is I don't know how to increment i after each element in xs is tested. 

For sub-problem 2, I want to return False as soon as even a single True appears in ys because that means there is a divisor other than 1 and n.

Comment: That is correct on both accounts. 1. Your `i` problem will go away when you give it a try and look at some examples of `map`. 2. A function you might be looking for is [any](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/any_f.html).

Comment: Ah I see the "any" makes sense. So for map, I think I should be doing: `map(n rem i == 0) xs` but I'm still a little confused on how to get i to equal the current element in xs.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Using the "<-" operator, I can make i take on a value in a range.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a loop, try to convert it to a tail recursion.

```
isPrimeHelper :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
isPrimeHelper p (i:is) 
    | i*i > p = True
    | p `rem` i == 0 = False
    | otherwise = isPrimeHelper p is

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime p = isPrimeHelper p [2..p]
```

the `isPrimeHelper` is the recursion version of the loop and the `i` appear in it is just like the `i` in the loop, and you can keep track of it.

for the equivalent Python code:

```py
def isPrimeHelper(p : int, xs : [int]):
  i = xs[0]
  if i*i >p:
    return True
  elif p % i == 0:
    return False
  else:
    return isPrimeHelper(p, xs[1:])
```

Comment: This is pretty elegant. But what does the "i*i > p" check for?

Comment: @Prithvi Boinpally kind of a trick when calculating prime number. We only need to check factors that are small the square root of the number (as the factors are kind of symmetrical) eg. for 18 -> 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18; 2 and 9 pair up, 3 and 6 pair up so we only need to check 2 and 3 which is smaller then sqrt(18)